# How to extract date with format 2014 January 1? PHP

Tags: php

I have this code. I want to extact 2014 January 1 in the string but I keep on getting null

```
$paragraph = "today is 2014 January 1";

preg_match_all('/(\d{4}/) \b(?:Jan(?:uary)?|Feb(?:ruary)?|Mar(?:ch)?|Apr(?:il)?|May?|Jun(?:e)?|Jul(?:y)?|Aug(?:ust)?|Sept(?:ember)?|Oct(?:ober)?|Nov(?:ember)?|Dec(?:ember)?) (\d|\d{2}) ', $paragraph, $date);

var_dump($date);
```

but the var_dump($date) returns null

Comment: Don't use _regex_ to parse dates. Use [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](http://in.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)

Comment: It could be resolved with that but I need to extract first the date from the string?

Comment: What is your expected output _actually_ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following, you only had to do some adjustments to the regexp.

```
$paragraph = "today is 2014 January 1, and tomorrow will be 2015 March 12";

$date = Array();

// Find all dates
preg_match_all('@((?:\d{4}) (?:Jan(?:uary)?|Feb(?:ruary)?|Mar(?:ch)?|Apr(?:il)?|May?|Jun(?:e)?|Jul(?:y)?|Aug(?:ust)?|Sept(?:ember)?|Oct(?:ober)?|Nov(?:ember)?|Dec(?:ember)) (?:\d{1,2}))@', $paragraph, $date);

// Display results
echo '<pre>';
print_r($date[0]);
echo '</pre>';

// Iterate over the results
$total = count($date[0]);
for($i=0;$i<$total;$i++){
    // Use the following if you want to change the display format
    date_create_from_format('Y-M-d', $date[0][$i]);
    echo $date[0][$i].'<br />';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could go with `DateTime::createFromFormat()` for your example , but you need to escape each and every character since there is **today is** text which doesn't represent a date format.

```
<?php
$paragraph = "today is 2014 January 1";
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('\t\o\d\a\y \i\s Y F j', $paragraph);
echo $date->format('Y F j'); //"prints" 2014 January 1
```